# How to rename upload file from input text

Tags: python, html, django, upload, rename

Im a newbie to code so im quite bad at it. Im using Django for the framework. Currently this is my html code for the user input.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>uploader</title>
  <style>
    h1 {
      font-size: 2em;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #777777;
      text-align: center
    }
    table {
      margin: auto;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

   <h1>
      {{what}}
      <h3><p style="text-align: left;text-decoration: none;"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Back</p></a></h3>
  </h1>
 <hr>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <fieldset>
   Category of the device:<br>
   <input type="text" name="category" value="" required id="cat">
   <br>
   Model:<br>
   <input type="text" name="model" value="" required id="mod">
 <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Upload File" class="submit" name="submit" />
 <input type="file" name="file"/>

 </fieldset>

        </form>


      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'what':'Upload Files'})


def upload(request):
try:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
        try:    
            myfile = request.FILES['file']
            category = request.POST['category']
            model = request.POST['model']
            validate_file_extension(myfile)
            fs = FileSystemStorage(location='uploaded/')
            filename = request.FILES['filename'].name
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))
            modified_name = "{}_{}_{}".format(filename, category, modle)
            filename = fs.save(modified_name, myfile)
            return redirect("/success")
        except:
            return redirect("/unsuccessful")
except:
    return redirect("/upload")

def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename):
    if not os.path.exists('uploaded/'):
        os.mkdir('uploaded/')
    with open('uploaded/' + filename, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

How do i rename the file that the user uploaded to have the text they input to the back of their filename with "_".

eg:

```
filename = myfile
category = camera 
model    = XYZ123
```

The file should be renamed to "myfile_camera_XYZ123".

Comment: You must do it in views. Could you post it ?

Comment: Sure! i've edited it

Comment: Is the form associated to a model ?

Comment: nope it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the form values, `category`, and `model`. And then get the filename from uploaded file.

```
category = request.POST['category']
model = request.POST['model']

# And filename
filename = request.FILES['filename'].name


modified_name = "{}_{}_{}".format(filename, category, modle)
filename = fs.save(modified_name, myfile)
```

Comment: I dont get what you're trying to say i tried adding the code in but it doesnt work.

Comment: After getting the cateogry and model from form. And getting the original file name using request.FILES['filename'].name

Comment: Then create the modified name string. What is you don't understand this...?

Comment: I can get the category and model but I have MultiValueDictKeyError on this line of code:

"filename = request.FILES['filename'].name"

Comment: Oh. Sorry for that. I see `<input type="file" name="file" />` in your html just now. So try with `request.FILES['file'].name`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Currently im having this error..

    filename = fs.save(modified_name, myfile)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fs' referenced before assignment

Comment: Sure! I've updated it.


i don't know if i did it correctly, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I saw the updated code. Sadly I don't know where it cause this error. Can you find `fs` in your code. It may chance that fs will be in more than a place. Please check it.

Comment: Sure i'll check it

Comment: @jeffkoh Did you find out ? Perhaps please update your question with full code. I may help you .

Comment: I've tried finding it but i dont seem to be able to find another fs in my code and sure! if youre willing to help me, and by full code do u want everything in my folder?if so can i pm u somewhere else instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here a better way to proceed with django form.

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = forms.FileField()

# views.py
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            validate_file_extension(data.file)
            file_ext = data.file.split(".")[-1]
            file_core = data.file.replace('.'+file_ext, '')
            filename = '{0}_{1}_{2}.{3}'.format(file_core, data.category, data.model, file_ext)
            handle_uploaded_file(filename)
            # ... fill the end
```

Comment: Theres a dict error, i cant over "file_ext = data.file.split(".")[-1]"
and when u  said fill the end, what do i do with the excepts? if i change it to else its shows syntax error

Comment: forms.py fixed, my bad. Should be better. Not sure the code is 100% valid according to your project but it give you the main idea.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but in the cmd it the error shows:AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'file'


Does it mean anything?